# Alternate SQL Server query by performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Query which I am using:

```
select SUM(marks) 
from Table1 
where name = ? 
  and Date = (select top 1 Date 
              from Table1 
              where name =? 
                and Date < ? 
              order by Date desc)
```

Table1:

| id | name | marks | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 34 | 01/01/2021 |
| 2 | abc | 15 | 05/01/2021 |
| 3 | abc | 20 | 05/01/2021 |
| 4 | def | 34 | 05/01/2021 |
| 5 | abc | 12 | 10/01/2021 |

```
select sum(marks) 
from Table1 
where name ='abc' 
  and Date = (select top 1 Date 
              from Table1 
              where name = 'abc' 
                 and Date < 10/01/2021 
              order by Date desc)
```

Result `35`

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: thanks for asking ,i am asking for alternate query which take less time to fetch required result?

Comment: What makes you think the current query is slow? For performance related questions we need a copy of the execution plan, using "Paste The Plan"

Comment: @KuldeepSingh, Look at the answer and mark it as `useful` appropriately. If it does not help, add a `comment`. Do not keep the question open even if some solution is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `RANK()` would take comparatively less time:

```
select sum(marks)
from
   (
   select *, rank()OVER(order by date desc) as rnk
   from table1
   where name ='abc' and Date < '10/01/2021'
   ) as we
where rnk=1
```

Result: `35`

**Explanation:**

Your query is using sub-query in WHERE clause which will check for each and every condition and you are filtering for name `abc` 2 times. Alternatively I am doing it once and feeding subquery in `FROM` clause that significantly saves time.

Look at the demo *[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ec845a92906364980f9350dadbc8da99)* with time elapsed (have made some additional dummy data to check time)